# How to change the colour back to the original following \color

Tags: color

I have this command set up: `\newcommand\blue[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}`

In my document, I use `\color{blue}`.

Then I'd like to change the colour back to the original. Is there a way I can do this without

1. scoping the `\color{blue}` or
2. hardcoding the colour `\color{black}`.

Comment: Only way is `\newcommand\blue[1]{\bgroup\color{blue}#1\egroup}` or use `\newcommand\blue[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}`

Comment: `\color` is a command to use with care. It will turn the whole text into blue (in your case). It's better, as Harish Kumar proposed, to restrict it's usage to `\textcolor{blue}{text}`

Comment: @HarishKumar: You should make an answer ;-)

Comment: @HarishKumar but that is explicitly what the question asks that you don't do in (1.) :-)

Comment: "Changing the color back to the original" is sort of the definition of scoping....

Comment: @Derek no scoping implies a tex group, which would also set back the current font and current macro definitions and....

Comment: Could you explain why the usual approach of grouping or using `\textcolor` (which does the same) is not applicable?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is why I left a comment ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\def\zz{\edef\zzz{\pdfliteral{\current@color}}}%pdftex version
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\color{green}\zz one two \color{blue} three four \zzz five

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are one hell of Hacker! ;-) +1

Answer (score 2):

Store the colours used in your document in a stack. The [fifo-stack](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fifo-stack) package provides the necessary functionality.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fifo-stack}
\FSCreate{colors}{black}
\makeatletter
\let\old@color\color
\renewcommand\color[1]{\FSPush{colors}{#1}\old@color{#1}}
\newcommand\colorend{\FSPop{colors}\old@color{\FSTop{colors}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par
\color{blue}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par
\color{red}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par
\colorend
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par
\colorend
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Each time you use a colour, it goes on the stack. The `\colorend` macro discards the top of the stack (the current colour) and then sets the colour to whatever is now at the top.

[image: colours]